# How to insert into a table the form element (Drupal 8)?

Tags: drupal-8

Please help. There is a form in a table. How to insert into a table, the form element such as textfield?

```
$header = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']; 
$rows[] = array('val1', 'val2', 'val3');

$form['user_counters'] = array('#type' => 'table', 
                               '#header' => $header, 
                               '#rows' => $rows, 
                         );
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers here should get you started: [Embed controls 8 #table element?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185032/embed-controls-8-table-element)

The short version is that your $rows should go directly into the render array instead of #rows.

This is probably because form building explicitly skips over any array keys that could be considered properties (start with '#'. See [Element::children()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element.php/function/Element%3A%3Achildren/8.2.x)), so even if your form fields render in the table, they won't be part of the form.